# Python regex with one operator or the other, but not both

Tags: python, regex

I want to use a regular expression to match a lowercase letter followed by either a `+` and a digit or a `-` and a digit, or both, but not 2 times the same operator.

To be clear, these are acceptable

```
a
a+1
a-2
a+3-4
a-5+6
```

while these are not acceptable

```
a+1+2
a-3-4
```

My current expression is

```
r = re.compile(r"[a-z]{1}([+-]\d){0,2}?$")
```

which allows both the non-acceptable strings. How can I specify that if one operator has already been used, it cannot appear twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[a-z](?!(\+\d\+\d)|(\-\d\-\d))((\+|\-)\d)*
```

And verbose version (which is better, use it):

```
[a-z]                     # find this
(?!                       # not followed by:
  (\+\d\+\d) | (\-\d\-\d) #                  (this or that)
)
(
  (\+|\-)\d               # followed by this
)*                        # 0 or more times
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a backreference within a negative lookahead (the overall regex will have to change a little bit though):

```
[a-z](?:([+-])\d(?:(?!\1)[+-]\d)?)?$
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/yXZtB7/1)

Instead of `([+-]\d){0,2}?`, I have made the possible two repeats like this: `([+-])\d(?:(?!\1)[+-]\d)?`, the first occurrence of operator and number being `([+-])\d` and the second `(?:(?!\1)[+-]\d)?`.

In the first occurrence, the regex is storing the matched value (either `+` or `-`) and in the second, it is making sure this matched value is not matched `(?!\1)[+-]` (`(?! ... )` is the syntax for negative lookahead so that `[+-]` cannot be something that this negative lookahead matches)

Answer (score 2):

You can branch these in two scenario's so:

```
r = re.compile(r'^[a-z]([+]\d([-]\d)?|[-]\d([+]\d)?)?$')
```

([**regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/PAtxj7/1/))

So we basically have two branches here:

1. `[+]\d([-]\d)?`: we start with a `+`, a digit and optionally a `-` and a digit; and
2. `[-]\d([+]\d)?`: we start with a `-`, a digit and optionally a `+` and a digit.

We then make a union between the the two, and make this optional as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(?!(.+?\+){2,}|(.*?\-){2,})[a-z][\d+-]*
```

[Demo at regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/PI13LS/1)

Explanation:

- `(?!(.+?\+){2,}|(.*?\-){2,})` negative look ahead asserts that there are not more than two occurrence of `+` or `-`
- `[a-z]`  matches lower case character
- `[\d+-]*` matches zero or more digits, `+` or `-`